# Visual Studio не там ищет файл

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Когда ставил Xamarin выбрал местоположением для установки Android SDK папку на несистемном диске. Visual Studio писал ошибку:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1933,3): error MSB6004: Указанное расположение исполняемого файла задачи "D:\XamarinAndroidSdk\\bin\javac.exe" является недопустимым.
```

Перенес папку на диск C:\ . В настройках выбрал новое место. Запускаю проект. Та же ошибка. В настройках опять папка на диске D:\ .

Переустановил. Во время установки выбрал папку на диске C:\ . Вот такая  ошибка:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(531,2): error : Could not find android.jar for API Level 23. This means the Android SDK platform for API Level 23 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (D:\XamarinAndroidSdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar missing.)
```

В настройках вроде все правильно.

Как исправить?

Upd: исправил. Переустановил Xamarin:)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте действия описанные на [форуме Xamarin](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56085/error-building-api-level-23-xamarin-4-upgrade), а именно:

> You just need to remove the content of the %USER%\AppData\Local\Xamarin content and than just run the Xamarin Installer again.
>
> After that clean your solution and build the top most android project.

или по-нашему

1. Удалите содержимое папки **%USER%\AppData\Local\Xamarin**
2. Выполните команду **clean** для вашего solution.
3. Сделайте **build** проекта.

Обратите внимание, первый раз build будет выполняться очень долго.